# No trace of the child process

Tags: c, process, signals, fork, child-process

I forked a child and I am trying to synchronize them so they print

```
child 0
parent 0
child 1
parent 1
```

I have to use `sigsuspend` though, this is my code for the moment and all I get is `parent suspend`. There is no trace of the child.

```
int c=0, receivedP=0, receivedC=0;
sigset_t setParent, setChild;
void handler(int s){
    if(s==SIGUSR1){
        receivedC=1;
        printf("parent --sig1--> child\n");
        c++;
    }
    else{
        receivedP=1;
        printf("child --sig2--> parent\n");
    }
}
void child(){
    sigfillset(&setChild);
    sigdelset(&setChild,SIGUSR1);
    sigdelset(&setChild,SIGINT); //this makes me able to terminate the program at any time
    while(1){
        if(receivedC==0){
            printf("child suspend\n");
            sigsuspend(&setChild);
        }
        receivedC=0;
        printf("child %d\n",c);
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
    }
}
void parent(pid_t pf){
    sigfillset(&setParent);
    sigdelset(&setParent,SIGUSR2);
    sigdelset(&setParent,SIGINT); //this makes me able to terminate the program at any time
    kill(pf,SIGUSR1);
    while(1){
        if(receivedP==0){
            printf("parent suspend\n");
            sigsuspend(&setParent);
        }
        receivedP=0;
        printf("parent %d\n",c);
        kill(pf,SIGUSR1);
    }
}
int main(){
    signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
    signal(SIGUSR2,handler);
    pid_t p;
    p= fork();
    if(!p)child();
    else parent(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Anybody knows what's causing this?

Comment: 1) You must not call async-unsafe functions like `printf()` in signal-handlers. 2) You must not access non lock-free-`_Atomic`, non-`volatile sig_atomic_t` objects from both normal code and inside of a signal-handler. Otherwise, undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF ok so I removed `printf()` from `handler(int s)`. I don't understand `2)`

Comment: @EOF What you say is true in general, but the whole point of `sigsuspend` is that you can arrange to have async signals delivered _only_ at a safe point - i.e. when the main thread of execution has just called `sigsuspend`.  If done correctly, it's OK to do arbitrary work in the signal handlers.  (This program does not appear to do it correctly.)

Comment: @Eirovi I think you have a race condition.  Please post the **complete, unedited** output of `strace -f ./a.out`.

Comment: @zwol: As far as I can tell, `sigsuspend()` suffers from the same problem as `select()`, in that you cannot atomically test whether you want to wait at all. Unfortunately there's no `psigsuspend()` equivalent to `pselect()` AFAIK. The closest is `sigwait[info]()`, which appears sane.

Comment: @EOF I may have mixed up `sigsuspend` with `sigwait` and/or `pselect` in my head.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.

Comment: the signal event is asynchronous to the execution of the code.  So a 0/1/0... sequencing will not work.  Suggest having the signal handler just increment and having the parent/child function just decrement However, even this will not prevent a race condition on the handling of the counters

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three return states, not just two.  (usually best to use a `switch()`  with cases of 0=child, -1=error, and default=parent. )

Comment: if you read the man page for `signal()` you will note that its' usage is discouraged, and suggests using: `sigaction()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running foul of one of the classic problems with signals.

```
while(1){
    if(receivedP==0){
        printf("parent suspend\n");
        sigsuspend(&setParent);
    }
    receivedP=0;
    printf("parent %d\n",c);
    kill(pf,SIGUSR1);
}
```

Imagine what happens if the signal from the child arrives *in between* the instructions for `if(receivedP==0)` and `sigsuspend(&setParent)`.  The handler will execute, and will set `receivedP` to one, but the main loop *won't check it again*; it will go into `sigsuspend` and never come out.

In order to use `sigsuspend` safely, you need to have the signals you care about be blocked at all times when the program is *not* calling `sigsuspend`.  You do that with `sigprocmask`.  It's also necessary to ensure that the signals are blocked *during the execution of the handler*, which requires you to use `sigaction` instead of `signal` (but you should do that anyway, as `signal` is severely underspecified and system-to-system variations *will* bite you in the ass).

Once you ensure that the signal can *only* be delivered during a `sigsuspend`, you no longer need the `receivedP` and `receivedC` variables; you know that the signal happened, or `sigsuspend` would not have returned.  (This would not be true if your program was waiting for more than a single signal in each process, but at that point things get much more complicated; don't worry about it till it comes up.)

In fact, once you ensure that, you don't need to do *anything* in the signal handler.  Your counter variable can be local to `parent` and `child`.  It's always best to do as little in a signal handler as possible; the letter of the C standard allows you to do almost nothing without risking undefined behavior, and POSIX only opens it up a little bit more.  (Exercise for you: change this program to use [`sigwaitinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigwaitinfo) so that it doesn't need handler functions at all.)

This modification of your program works reliably for me.  I also corrected a number of other style problems and minor errors: note the loops in `parent` and `child` doing things in different orders, the error checking in `main`, and that I am *only* blocking `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, because there are several other signals that should be allowed to terminate the process (`SIGTERM`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGSEGV`, …) and you don't want to have to maintain a list.  It is sufficient to block the signals that the program has installed handlers for.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handler(int unused)
{
}

static void child(sigset_t *ss)
{
  unsigned int c = 0;
  pid_t parent_pid = getppid();

  sigdelset(ss, SIGUSR1);
  for (;;) {
    sigsuspend(ss);
    printf("child %u\n", c++);
    kill(parent_pid, SIGUSR2);
  }
}

static void parent(sigset_t *ss, pid_t child_pid)
{
  unsigned int c = 0;

  sigdelset(ss, SIGUSR2);
  for (;;) {
    printf("parent %u\n", c++);
    kill(child_pid, SIGUSR1);
    sigsuspend(ss);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  // Ensure line-buffered stdout.
  if (setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0)) {
    perror("setvbuf");
    return 1;
  }

  // This signal mask is in effect at all times _except_ when sleeping
  // in sigsuspend().  Note that _only_ the signals used for IPC are
  // blocked.  After forking, each process will modify it appropriately
  // for its own use of sigsuspend(); this does not affect the kernel-side
  // copy made by sigprocmask().
  sigset_t ss;
  sigemptyset(&ss);
  sigaddset(&ss, SIGUSR1);
  sigaddset(&ss, SIGUSR2);

  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, 0)) {
    perror("sigprocmask");
    return 1;
  }

  // Always use sigaction(), not signal(); signal() is underspecified.
  // The mask here is the signal mask to use _while the handler is
  // executing_; it should also block both IPC signals.
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sa.sa_mask    = ss;
  sa.sa_flags   = SA_RESTART;
  if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, 0) || sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, 0)) {
    perror("sigaction");
    return 1;
  }

  pid_t child_pid = fork();
  if (child_pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  }

  if (child_pid == 0)
    child(&ss);
  else
    parent(&ss, child_pid);

  // we never get here but the compiler might not know that
  return 0;
}
```

I recommend you read the GNU C Library Manual's [section on signal handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html) all the way through; it contains several other bits of helpful advice on using signals safely.